# Google CloudSQL instance non-responsive, how to get support?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When it comes to databases, we want to leave managing them to the pros, which is why we went for a managed solution in the form of a CloudSQL 2nd gen db instance. Today the instance stopped responding, I clicked restart, it has been restarting for hours and is not responding, I have tried clone the instance, also not responding.

I don't know what else to do, our db is crippled and the service that uses it is down. These things happen, fine.

The thing that shocked me is that I am unable to contact anybody to resolve this problem. I understand that I can pay for a support subscription, $150p/m and up. This confuses me though, the GCloud console UI is not responding, am I incorrect in assuming I should not have to pay for support for the core product to at least work?

This leads me to my main question, **if I want to continue using Google Cloud products in production, do I NEED a support subscription?**

Comment: The Cloud SQL team encourages users to use Stack Overflow to ask questions for troubleshooting. For privacy sensitive issues, a support package is needed. The email alias cloud-sql@google.com can be used as well but the support from that channel is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for your response Herman, I understand this, in cases where users have small production deployments, and some event causes a critical outage (such as a db going down), is a support subscription the only means of getting a quick response?

Comment: Happened to us today. Production Cloud 2nd generation. Seems that the culprit is "[Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 5087ms. The settings might not be optimal." Too bad no one in the team touched that setting so no one saw that coming.

Comment: @AlnDvs, yes, a quick response is only guaranteed by a support subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to us yesterday. The cloud SQL instance did not respond for an hour and a half (from 18h to 19:30h GTM+1).

We couldn't do absolutely nothing, we tried to backup the instance to a bucket but the command was returning an error saying that another operation is in progress.

We are a small startup and we can't pay for a support plan, but when we hired the cloud SQL service we thought that this kind of situations doesn't happen.

**Honestly, after this I believe that Cloud SQL is not a good option if you do not contract at the same time a gold or platinum support plan.** It is frustrating that something fails and you can not do anything, or even report the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) command line tool in your active shell, instead of the console UI. Try exporting the data from your SQL instance to google cloud storage bucket by using this command:

```
gcloud sql instances \
export <sql-instnace-name> \
gs://<bucket-name>/backup.sql
```

The SQL instance's service account by default has read and write access to google cloud storage bucket.

Create a new SQL instance using this command:

```
gcloud sql instances \
create <new-sql-instance-name>
```

Now, add the data to the new SQL instance using this command:

```
gcloud sql instances \
import <new-sql-instance-name> \
gs://<bucket-name>/backup.sql
```

Comment: Note: Do this as first thing. We tried restarting the instance and now we cannot even do this because it tries to complete the restart before running anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can get [free or premium support here](https://cloud.google.com/support/). You do not need a subscription to get help; it all depends on your needs and the level of urgency you estimate for eventual future problems.

If you have a recent backup of your database, you may consider re-creating it in another instance, from there.

You may consider posting your issue in the G[oogle Cloud SQL Product Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/list). This way, it will enjoy much better visibility from developers and Google support, without attracting any extra costs.

Comment: You need a subscription to get a quick response. This is a caveat that is not immediately obvious when making use of the Google Cloud services. In a production setting, not being able to recover a database is a massive concern. In our case it took 10 hours before the db was responsive, this would have been a major loss for us if it was our main db. To be clear, cloning a new db from a backup only responded after the 10 hours.