# Google Cloud SQL Instance does not start

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I've stopped my Google Cloud SQL 2nd generation instance on 02 Jan this year.

Today I'm trying to start it again but just receives an error:

> "Could not complete the operation"

This is the only info in the logs:

> {
>    protoPayload: {…}
>    insertId: "54775E151DAA9.A2E1542.960A7970"
>    resource: {…}
>    timestamp: "2017-02-01T10:55:00.523Z"
>    severity: "ERROR"
>    logName: "projects/hti-info-center/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
>   }

All functions including restoring of backups are disabled as the instance is stopped.

Is there anywhere I can get more information about the instance's current state in order to try and resolve this issue, without having to sign up for a Google Support package?

Comment: We have exactly the same error and question. W Kok, have you managed to resolve the issue without having to sign up for a support package?

Comment: No not at all. I'm still at a loss. I will definitely post here if it gets resolved, hoping you'd do the same?

Comment: i have the same problem. so i'm paying for an instance that i can't start, and i can't retrieve a backup to use on another instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar situation it's happening to me, post a comment here: https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20log&groupby=&sort=&id=216

It seems that they have a bug with the cloud SQL instances since Jan 25th ([although I have experimented a similar error on January 13th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548375/google-cloudsql-instance-non-responsive-how-to-get-support/41651307#41651307)).
Very very frustrating...

In your case, if the instance is stopped, have you tried to create a clone or export the data and create a new instance?

Comment: Maybe try again, I just got mine to restart with no issues.

Comment: Yes, today I can start my instance! Thank you everyone for sharing in getting Google to action.

Answer (score 1):

This was suggested by Google support, and worked for me:

try to start your service via gcloud by running the following command:

```
gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --activation-policy=[ACTIVATION_POLICY]
```

and set the activation policy to "ALWAYS" or "ON_DEMAND".